# Where do files go if you accidentially delete the path?

Tags: windows

If I use the rename C function and rename something without a path, where does it go to?

Comment: Try it and see.  In most filesystems, the file does not go anywhere - its directory entry is modified.

Comment: Search the filename in "Type here to search", left bottom of your desktop window.

Comment: I tried it and i cant find the files anywhere.